# How to get source code in CKEditor in the edit mode + rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ckeditor

I am a rails developer and making one application in which I used CKEditor. In this editor I wrote a sample HTML source code and then submitted. The source code has been interpreted well in the front-end like a sample GUI. But after that I wanted to edit the source code from the same CKEditor in the edit mode, at that time it is coming like an interface inside the editor instead the same source code.

I attached the screen shots, so kindly have a look at them and give me the response.[image] [image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the second image I don't see that you have the button "Source" clicked as in the first image..

Comment: You can see that at top bar right most

Comment: So basically you want is when you are in edit mode it should directly show the source without having the source button clicked ??

Comment: Exactly my friend. Even if I click on the Source button it is just returning <p> tags.

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the most elegant solution, but I think it should work.

I would use jQuery or javascript to detect which page you are on (basically if there is a /edit at the end of your URL)  and if it is it should add this to your CKEditor config:

```
config.startupMode = 'source';
```

Also make sure to execute this script before the CKEditor loads.